# Actualización de cookbooks empezó a arrojar "NoMethodError: undefined method `artifact' for Chef::Resource::Script"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Este bloque de codigo dejo de funcionar luego de una actualizacion de los cookbooks en amazon Opsworks, la modificacion de un "recipe"

```
# Gracefully restart queue workers
script "restart_queue_worker" do
    interpreter "bash"
    user "root"
    cwd "#{app_path_current}"
    code <<-EOH
    php artisan queue:restart
    EOH
    only_if { ::File.directory?("#{app_path_current}") }
end

# download the app artifact
artifact = "/tmp/#{app[:shortname]}.tar.gz"
s3_file "#{artifact}" do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0644"
    action :create

    remote_path "#{s3_file_path}"
    bucket "#{s3_bucket}"

    aws_access_key_id app[:app_source][:user]
    aws_secret_access_key app[:app_source][:password]

end
```

El error que aparecio fue

```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `artifact' for Chef::Resource::Script
```

No hubieron otros cambios, aparte de ese recipe no relacionado que se modifico. al volver atras los cambios, tampoco da resultado y el error persiste.

Answer (score 1):

Despues de batallar un tiempo, encontre que el error estaba en el bloque de codigo anterior a donde se producia el error,
 por alguna razon, el compilador de chef o ruby ahora era mas sensible a los espacios

```
# Gracefully restart queue workers
script "restart_queue_worker" do
    interpreter "bash"
    user "root"
    cwd "#{app_path_current}"
    code <<-EOH
    php artisan queue:restart
    EOH[ ]  <<<< --------------------------- aqui habia un espacio en blanco 
    only_if { ::File.directory?("#{app_path_current}") }
end
```

Tal vez ese espacio en blanco siempre estubo, y una de dos opciones ocurrio alparecer el cambio de alguna version de chef lo hizo mas sensible a ese espacio al final, o fue accidentalmente puesto ese espacio en algun punto sin ser percibido por git, y a partir de ese momento dejo de funcionar el script.

Ya que este problema es tipico en los sistema de php antiguos sensibles a espacios o caracteres invisibles los cuales son errores dificiles de encontrar decidi poner la solucion.

ya esta funcionando todo como debe ser.